# Flatten/merge a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
data = [{'average': 2, 'day': '2022-01-01'},
        {'average': 3, 'day': '2022-01-02'},
        {'average': 5, 'day': '2022-01-03'},
        {'sum': 8, 'day': '2022-01-01'},
        {'sum': 15, 'day': '2022-01-02'},
        {'sum': 9, 'day': '2022-01-03'},
        {'total_value': 19, 'day': '2022-01-01'},
        {'total_value': 99, 'day': '2022-01-02'},
        {'total_value': 15, 'day': '2022-01-03'}]
```

I want my output as:

```
output = [{'average': 2, 'sum': 8, 'total_value': 19, 'day': '2022-01-01'},
          {'average': 3, 'sum': 15, 'total_value': 99, 'day': '2022-01-02'},
          {'average': 5, 'sum': 9, 'total_value': 15, 'day': '2022-01-03'}]
```

The output puts the values together based off their date. My approaches so far have been to try and separate everything out into different dictionaries (date_dict, sum_dict, etc.) and then bringing them all together, but that doesn't seem to work and is extremely sloppy.

Comment: this dict is invalid - same key cannot appear more than once

Comment: "I have a list of dictionaries:" Please show code that actually corresponds to the desired input. What you show is a single dictionary, where most of the declared keys will be overwritten.

Comment: Yeah formatting was wrong. Fixed it. Apologies

Comment: "Is this possible in python?" Well, what do you imagine are the logical steps needed in order to compute the result? Did you try to write code to follow those steps? What is the actual question underlying this? We are just manipulating a bit of data; of course it should be *possible*.

Comment: Hint: what if you had a dictionary that mapped from a given day string to the other pieces of information for that day? Can you see how to create that from the input? Can you see how to create the output from there?

Comment: Honestly, I am not even sure how to approach it. I'm a bit lost on how this would be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate over data and create a dictionary using `day` as key:

```
data = [{'average': 2, 'day': '2022-01-01'},
    {'average': 3, 'day': '2022-01-02'},
    {'average': 5, 'day': '2022-01-03'},
    {'sum': 8, 'day': '2022-01-01'},
    {'sum': 15, 'day': '2022-01-02'},
    {'sum': 9, 'day': '2022-01-03'},
    {'total_value': 19, 'day': '2022-01-01'},
    {'total_value': 99, 'day': '2022-01-02'},
    {'total_value': 15, 'day': '2022-01-03'}]

output = {}

for item in data:
    if item['day'] not in output:
        output[item['day']] = item
    else:
        output[item['day']].update(item)

print(list(output.values()))
```

Out:

```
[
    {'average': 2, 'day': '2022-01-01', 'sum': 8, 'total_value': 19},
    {'average': 3, 'day': '2022-01-02', 'sum': 15, 'total_value': 99}, 
    {'average': 5, 'day': '2022-01-03', 'sum': 9, 'total_value': 15}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a bit of fun and made it with dict/list comprehension. Check out that neat `|` operator in python 3.9+ :-)

### Python <3.9

```
from collections import ChainMap
data_grouped_by_day  = {
    day : dict(ChainMap(*[d for d in data if d["day"] == day ]))
    for day in {d["day"] for d in data }
}
for day, group_data in data_grouped_by_day.items():
    group_data.update(day=day)
result = list(data_grouped_by_day.values())
```

### Python 3.9+

```
from collections import ChainMap
result = [
    dict(ChainMap(*[d for d in data if d["day"] == day ])) | {"day" : day}
    for day in {d["day"] for d in data}
]
```

The output in both cases is (keys order may vary)

```
[{'total_value': 99, 'day': '2022-01-02', 'sum': 15, 'average': 3},
 {'total_value': 15, 'day': '2022-01-03', 'sum': 9, 'average': 5},
 {'total_value': 19, 'day': '2022-01-01', 'sum': 8, 'average': 2}]
```